# Date comparison always returns true - Swift

Tags: swift, date

I want to track when was the last time the user refreshed the api, so I decided to do it like this:

```
@AppStorage("lastTimeUserRefreshedApi") var lastTimeUserRefreshedApi: Date = Date()

func canUserRefreshAPI() -> Bool {
    let readyToBeRefreshed: Date = lastTimeUserRefreshedApi.addingTimeInterval(5) // in seconds
    let currentTime: Date = Date()
    var canUserRefresh: Bool = false
    
    if(currentTime > readyToBeRefreshed) {
        canUserRefresh = true
        lastTimeUserRefreshedApi = lastTimeUserRefreshedApi.addingTimeInterval(5)
    } else {
        canUserRefresh = false
    }
    
    return canUserRefresh
}
```

The problem is that it's always returning true, but why? Also is there a simpler way to do this?

Thanks

EDIT:

This is the extension I'm using to be able to store Date in the @AppStorage:

```
extension Date: RawRepresentable {
    public var rawValue: String {
        self.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.description
    }
    
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
        self = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: Double(rawValue) ?? 0.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you inspect the values of `currentTime` and `readyToBeRefreshed`?

Comment: @jnpdx checking

Comment: @Albert are you trying to refresh it every five seconds?

Comment: You should be adding five seconds to the current time instead of adding to the lastTimeUserRefreshedApi

Comment: @LeoDabus yep, not sure if you are thinking about a timer, but I tried with a timer but the thing is that when the user comes from the background the next day and wants to refresh, then he/she has to wait for that times, and that doesn't apply. So I thought to store the timestamp

Comment: I never said to use a timer. But this should be pretty straight forward saving a date to user defaults

Comment: @LeoDabus yeah saving it is working, that's not the issue. Also if I add like you say +5 to current time, then let's compare, previous time at 1pm, is currenttime+5 greater than 1pm? It will always return true. I don't think that's correct.

Comment: Btw I think you should always update the UI when the app comes from background if you are really refreshing it every 5 seconds.

Comment: @LeoDabus Well if the app comes from the background after the app was closed it updates yes, if it's just minimized it doesn't, it'll be a paid feature to be able to refresh more often while I solve some concurrency problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making it much harder than it should. Just save the "expiration" date. When you read it just compare if it is past or not.

```
@AppStorage("expiration")
var expiration: Date = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)

func canUserRefreshAPI() -> Bool {
    let now = Date()
    if expiration < now {
        expiration = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```